# Python - reducing values of dataframe field based on string match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm struggling with some data clean up within values of a field in a panda dataframe. I checked for solutions here but couldnt find any that would help. Hopefully you guys can assist me. Here is a couple of examples of what I would like to achieve:

Examples of values in the field:

```
first value  ABC 123  /  ABC 456  /  DEF 123  / DEF 456

second value  DEF 456  /  DEF 789  /  GHI 123  / JKL 789
```

Output:

```
first value DEF 123 / DEF 456

second value DEF 456 / DEF 789
```

In other words, purging all codes not starting with "DEF".
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: df.loc[~df['column_name'].startswith('DEF')]

Comment: @Chris I'm getting an error message : AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'startswith'. Just to clarify, "ABC 123 / ABC 456 / DEF 123 / DEF 456" is a starting value that I want to transform to DEF 123 / DEF 456. In other words, asking python to take a look at each code within the value and only concatenate the ones matching my criteria (starting with "DEF"). Thanks!